# What is Fastest way to query a database android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database that contains 35000 records, and can easily get up to about 60000 records, 
What is the best way to query these data? Will ORMLite or GreenDAO be usefull? Or should i just stick with Cursor?

Answer (score 4):

That depends on what you mean by "best".

**Fastest, most flexible, best integration with Android library functions**: Stick with Cursor. Since ORMs are just wrappers around the native Android cursors, they are unlikely to be *faster* than direct access. In many cases, the Android UI library classes are optimized for Cursors (e.g. [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html), which allows you to bind a cursor to a UI list).

**Most readable, most maintainable**: An ORM *might* help here, but that depends on a lot of factors, including your project complexity, your application architecture, etc.

See the following programmers.se question for more information:

- [Does it make sense to use ORM in Android development?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/156160/33843)